# How to Terminate Script after a certain number of output

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that does some processing/logging stuff, and writes this to a file. It runs continuously until user terminates it.  What I want to do is to auto termination- run this script continuously until it fills the file up to a certain size or number of lines specified by user. Is this possible?

I can't think of how this can be done because i can't use conditionals if this script is continuous. I can only think of using threads, but i am a beginner at this, and don't want it to be so complex.

Comment: Use the head command

Comment: Your question is terse.  If `this` script is continuous. Could you put the script that writes to the file in question. Questions  should be [mcve]s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @123 said, you can use `head` to limit the output to a given number of lines like

```
continuous_command | head -n 20 > output_file
```

would show the first 20 lines, then when `continuous_command` tried to print its 21st it would fail because the other end of the pipe has exited, so `continuous_command` would get a `SIGPIPE` signal, which usually causes a program to terminate.

You can remove the `> output_file` part if you want the output to go to the terminal instead of a file

Comment: I guess the op is required to redirect to the results to the file in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
lines=$(cat file | wc -l)
if [ "$lines" -gt "some_value" ] ; then kill -9 "job_id" ; fi
```

Comment: OP says no conditionals, _i can't use conditionals if this script is continuous_

Comment: How about putting a conditional externally? And when `file` gets bigger than a certain size, doing a `kill -9` to the job?

Comment: Please clarify with the author before posting answers, to avoid getting downvoted.

Comment: @Inian : The op probably didn't meant `no conditionals`. They may be (mistakenly) under the impression that they can't apply conditionals here.